# I often hear $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on $L$, but why (how)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, group-actions

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$
I often hear $\Gal(L/K)$ acts on $L$, but why(how) ?
$\Gal(L/K)×L\to L$ by $(σ,x)\mapsto σ(x)$, here, $σ$ is an element of $\Gal(L/K)$, which is a ring homomorphism  from $L$ to $L$ and identity on $K$, and $σ(x)$ means the image of $x$ by $σ$.
We can check the axioms of group action, so **in this way**, $\Gal(L/K)$ acts on $L$, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Where is your doubt (why(how))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Sometimes this is also called the "natural action" of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ on $L$.

Why is this action "natural"? As all symmetric groups, the group $S_L$ of all permutations on $L$ acts on $L$ in the obvious "natural" way. The set $\operatorname{Aut}(L)$ of all field automorphisms of $L$ is a subgroup of $S_L$, which inherits the natural action on $L$.
And by definition, $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is just the (element-wise) stabilizer of $K$ of the latter group action, which again inherits the natural action on $L$.

This approach has the additional benefit that it is clear that we get a group action. It is not necessary to check the axioms explicitly.

Taking the above approach a step further: If $X$ is a set and $G$ is a group of bijections $X \to X$ (with respect to the ordinary concatenation of mappings), you always have the "natural" action $f \bullet x = f(x)$ (where $f\in G$ and $x\in X$) of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: Strictly speaking Gal$(L/K)$ is only a subgroup of the stabilizer of $K$ since the stabilizer also contains permutations that are not homomorphisms.

Comment: @lhl73 thank you. you are right, in my enthusiasm I forgot about the field homomorphisms. I adjusted my answer to make it precise.